# How to center a button with respect to another button on top

Tags: html, css

I like to center a button with respect to the button on top.
As shown in the image, the button below is not centered.

I tried as

```css
.btn {
  padding: 16px 22px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all .3s linear;
  -o-transition: all .3s linear;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-common {
  background: #3498db;
}

.btn-xs {
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-common btn-xs" ng-click="currecnySuggestion(room)"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Book without payment</button>
    <button class="btn btn-common btn-xs btn-center" ng-click="currecnySuggestion(room)"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Book with payment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you mean width not the same?

Comment: yes not same. keeping the current width.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Like this? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/RVLejV

Comment: @MichaelCoker do you have any ideas to make it better than this? I thought the below one is centered to the top one looks nicer. Isn't it? Any better idea?

Comment: What's kind of odd here is that "pull-right," along the other class names, seems to indicate you're using the Bootstrap CSS framework. If that is the case, "pull-right" should make the buttons right-aligned.

Comment: @batuman if you're looking for design feedback, I'm not sure. It would depend on the rest of your UI. Seems like the elements could use some padding and margin and the font size could be bigger. You might also look on booking.com or hotels.com for feedback about buttons like that. booking.com is data driven and do a lot of testing of their UI so their interface should be a good place to get inspiration

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes you are right. I use Bootstrap CSS framework. I am just editing sbd's work. I am not good at web applications. Just started learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the width of `pull-right` (either explicitly, or by doing something like `display: inline-block` in order to have the wrapper shrink to fit elements), and add a `margin: auto` to the `btn-center`, it should work.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aysevqay/)

Comment: you need to add `width: 100%;` to `.btn` in css

Comment: @DanielH OP said `center`, not `stretch` =)